# Visual Basic date from DateTimePicker doesn't work in SQL

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just need to ask about DateTimePicker since when I run the query below, I get the correct data in between the month and days but the year is wrong. DATEOFTRANSACTION has varchar as data type.

Example scenario

DateTimePicker1 = 06/10/2017

DateTimePicker2 = 10/22/2017

**Database has:**

> 06/10/2017
>   
> 08/02/2017
>   
> 12/15/2017
>   
> 08/02/2018

**After running the query my display is:**

> 06/10/2017
>   
> 08/02/2017
>   
> 08/02/2018

**Query String to get dates in between Picker1 and Picker2**

```
Dim rsa As New OracleCommand(
    "SELECT * FROM DBOR WHERE DATEOFTRANSACTION BETWEEN '" 
    & Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy").ToString & "' AND '" 
    & Format(DateTimePicker2.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy").ToString & "'", con)
```

**My insert query is this**

```
Dim rs As New OracleCommand(
    "Insert into DBOR (OR_NUMBER,FIRSTNAME,MIDDLENAME,LASTNAME,DATEOFTRANSACTION,TIMEOFTRANSACTION, PRICE, CASHIER) values ('" 
    & RECEIPTform.Label1.Text & "', '" 
    & ADDCUSTOMERform.FirstName.Text & "','" 
    & ADDCUSTOMERform.MiddleName.Text & "','" 
    & ADDCUSTOMERform.LastName.Text & "' ,'" 
    & Format(Date.Now(), "MM/dd/yyyy") & "' , '" 
    & TimeOfDay.ToString("h:mm:ss tt") & "', '" 
    & TextBox1.Text & "', '" 
    & LOGINform.username.Text & "')", con)
```

Comment: Learn how to use parameters

Comment: Take a look at this (OracleCommand.Parameters Property): https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The DateTimePicker.Value property is a Date.  Your code is converting it to a string of a particular format.  If the DB column is  Date, pass a Date.  If the columns are not Date, they should be - the NET DB Providers are perfectly capable of storing and passing dates.  Use SQL Parameters - composing SQL need not be that tedious and error prone.

Comment: Also Oracle is not SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

First, as commented before, you need to use parameters instead of concatenating strings values. [OracleCommand.Parameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) ie:

```
OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT fullname FROM sup_sys.user_profile
                           WHERE domain_user_name = :userName", db);
oraCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("userName", domainUser));
```

Second, dates stored in DB as string in this format:

```
YEAR(YYYY/YY)[optional separatos]Month(MM)[optional separatos]DAY(DD)
```

alphabetical and chronological order match, other formats, not.

You still have to deal with the problem where your dates in DB are stored as `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY` ( I can't tell with data sample provided)

So, it is not enough that you convert your DateTimePicker in the formal `MM/DD/YYYY` because this string is sorted alphabetically and this does not match the chonologycal order you need.

You need to convert char field in dates or in string format `YYYY/MM/DD`

In order to do this, you need something like this

```
TO_DATE(DATEOFTRANSACTION,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

It will look like this:

```
OracleCommand rsa = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM DBOR 
                WHERE TO_DATE(DATEOFTRANSACTION,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
                BETWEEN iniDate = :iniDate AND endDate= :endDate", con);
rsa.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("iniDate", DateTimePicker1.Value));
rsa.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("endDate", DateTimePicker2.Value));
```

**EDIT:** I just realized it is used `MM/DD/YYYY` format, but I'll leave the previous comment for others to see probable problems.

Comment: so i did something like this:  rsa.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("@DateStart", Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "yyyy/MM/dd")))

Comment: but now im not filtering anything

Comment: For Oracle you have to use the `:` character instead of `@`

Comment: Also, as I mentioned, you need to convert `DATEOFTRANSACTION`. it is not able to be sorted in a chronological fashion as dates are stored in the wrong format for this scenario.

Comment: @EjEspiritu See my last edit, I added a full answer you can work with, I don't have visual studio nor Oracle to test it.